# How to hide items in Unity's top panel?

Tags: unity, panel, messaging-menu

I just updated to Natty and now the default top panel has icons for mail, chat, and power (lock, restart, etc.) In Lucid and Maverick I could just right click on them and remove from panel, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

How can I get rid of these icons?

**EDITED TO ADD SCREENSHOTS**

The indicator I want to get rid of is the one that looks like an envelope:

[image]

When I click it, it displays these choices:

[image]

Comment: Similar question: [How can I remove the default indicators and add custom ones?](http://askubuntu.com/q/152380/62483)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are talking about your indicators. To remove them at terminal type:

- To remove weather indicator - `sudo apt-get remove my-weather-indicator`.
- To remove battery status indicator - `sudo apt-get remove battery-status-indicator`.
- To remove evolution indicator - `sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator`
- To remove message indicator - ***sudo apt-get remove indicator-me indicator-messages***.

...Just do that to any indicator you are willing to remove from your default panel. Do not forget to add to the indicator file name hyphen plus indicator. Restart your system for your changes to take effect.

If you want them back you can as well do the reverse, by typing at the terminal the following:

To install weather indicator - sudo apt-get install weather-indicator. Do the same with other indicators you wish to install.Restart your system for your changes to take effect.

This is a list of indicators I could find for Oneiric Ocelot(Ubuntu 11.10) :[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators)

I hope that is what you are looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I tried it, but I'm not entirely sure what the various indicator names are. Is there a list somewhere? Also, once they are removed, do I need to restart my session to see them gone?

Comment: That's a great list, but unfortunately even though the indicator I really want to get rid of is displayed in a lot of the screenshots, it's not one of the ones that's listed as an answer. I'm updating my OP to show what I'm trying to hide/remove.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove indicator-me indicator-messages   .That would remove the message indicator. It is among the list above though.Next thing is to click on your power icon(extreme top right hand side of your screen),select 'Startup Applications' unchecked 'Evolution Alarm notification' and 'Mail Notification'.Take good care of your.

Comment: Once you have removed an indicator, run `sudo killall unity-panel-service` to get them gone.

Answer (score 16):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run the respective command of any indicator you want to remove. You can also use Software Center to remove indicators, Just search for the indicator you want to remove.

- **Session Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-session`

  Or search for "indicator-session" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Date & Time Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-datetime`

  Or search for "indicator-datetime" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Sound Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-sound`

  Or search for "indicator-sound" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Network Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome`

  Or search for "network-manager-gnome" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Power Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-power`

  Or search for "indicator-power" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Messages Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages`

  Or search for "indicator-messages" in Software Center.

[image]

- **Bluetooth Indicator**

  [image]

  `sudo apt-get remove gnome-bluetooth`

  Or search for "gnome-bluetooth" in Software Center.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The indicators all start with 'indicator-' you can easily find them in Software Center.

there's `indicator-messages` for the mail menu, `indicator-me` for the indicator showing your name, `indicator-power` for the battery (not sure about the name in Natty), `indicator-sound` for sound menu, `indicator-datetime` for thetime/date showing up, `indicator-network` for network connections like wireless/lan and `indicator-weather` for weather forecasts.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it didn't occur to me to look there!