# How to remove 'system settings' from title bar of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, startup-applications, gsettings, switch-user

I want to remove System settings, Displays, software up to Date from the unity bar (title bar) of the new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you talking about the top panel and those right side indicators? If so, this is a possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74986/how-to-hide-items-in-unitys-top-panel

Answer (score 0):

These cannot be removed from the power-cog.