# How can I remove the default indicators and add custom ones?

Tags: indicator, panel, messaging-menu

I am trying to use the old Ubuntu feature of adding/removing indicators from the top panel in 11.10/12.04, but cannot do so. I have these questions:

- How can I remove or add indicator applet at top panel?
- How can I erase or add a panel ?
- How can I erase switch user account from top panel since I am the only user in my computer ?
- How can I erase Startup applications and printers from top panel ?
- How can I erase the Messages indicator from the top panel?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Please also upvote it when you have a chance.

Comment: Similar question: [How to hide items in Unity's top panel?](http://askubuntu.com/q/74986/62483)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can no longer add/remove indicators or panels by right-clicking like you used to with older Ubuntu versions before 11.10.

> **Warning:** The default indicators (messages, networking, power, sound, user accounts, etc.) are tightly integrated with Unity since Ubuntu 11.10, and trying to remove them may cause problems.

- You can remove **these** default indicators without affecting the rest of the system:

  1. **Messages:** Remove package `indicator-messages`
  2. **Sound:** Remove package `indicator-sound`
  3. **Power:** Remove package `indicator-power`
  4. **Print Jobs:** Remove package `indicator-printers`
  5. **Date/Time:** Simply enable/disable from System Settings...Time & Date:
     [image]
- Removing **these** default indicators is NOT recommended or not possible without serious adverse effects:

  1. **Networking:** Provided by package *network-manager-gnome*. DO NOT remove unless you have a desktop with one wired ethernet connection and do not use VPNs.
  2. **User Accounts and System**: Both provided by the package *indicator-session*. Removing this package will remove the *Shutdown*, *Logout*, etc. options as well!

     - Editing the list shown in the System Menu (*Startup Applications*, *Printers*, etc.) is NOT possible without modifying the source.

#### Adding other indicators

Please see this question for a master-list of all the different indicators -- each answer/comments will tell you if it is available from PPAs or the Software Center:

> [**What Application Indicators are available?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Comment: To remove the date/time indicator your tip does not work anymore. You have to use dconf-editor as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic

Answer (score 4):

The top panel is static and cannot be moved.

If you would like to add indicators to your system, there are 2 ways:

1. Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for "indicators".  Install the indicators you wish to use.
2. Install them via the terminal, for example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install indicator-weather
   ```
3. To remove an indicator, simply use the remove button in the Ubuntu Software Center, or use apt, for example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove indicator-weather
   ```

Comment: how can I remove message indicator from panel since they are not seen at software center ?

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been removed from Ubuntu since 11.04

The only way to add or delete indicators, is to install them or uninstall them via **repos** or **Ubuntu software center**.

Comment: Mail, switch user etc. indicators cannot be seen in software center. Where can I remove ?

Comment: For mail paste this in terminal: sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages

Answer (score 0):

If you want a highly customizable panel with the Lucid feel, and don't mind loosing Unity, you could try gnome-classic session. I think it's very good.

Tutorial here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/more-classic-gnome-session-lands-in.html