# How can I choose which menubar indicators are shown in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the default indicators and add custom ones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152380/how-can-i-remove-the-default-indicators-and-add-custom-ones)

I'd like to be able to tweak the set of shortcuts on the right side of the menubar in 12.04  (e.g. remove the email shortcut, remove the wifi shortcut on my laptop, add a lock screen shortcut so I can lock the screen with a single click rather than facing the choice between two clicks and Ctrl-Alt-L). Is this possible? The only thing I can find to configure in the settings is the date/time display.

Comment: Remove `indicator-messaging`, what wifi shortcut? network manager?,I'm not sure you can add custom launchers to the Unity top panel at all.