# How can I remove an application indicator in the panel for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: indicator, hp, panel, hplip

The driver for my HP printer has installed an indicator in the panel. I have two problems with it.

First, its design doesn't fit that of the panel, so it looks ugly.

Second, it's not very consistent on when it's showed in the panel;  it first shows at startup, but if I close the application the indicator disappears.  And if I open it again, it appears briefly and then it gets removed automatically.

I would like to not have to close it manually every time for it to disappear.  And I would like it even better, if I didn't see it at all.

Any help with for configuring this indicator will be greatly appreciated. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Also look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74986/how-to-hide-items-in-unitys-top-panel

Answer (score 2):

Start by clicking on it and choose **Settings**.

Then check **Always Hide** and you're done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Good news is : you can uninstall that indicator.

I think the package you need to remove is [indicator-printers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/indicator-printers) :

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-printers
```

Then just reboot or reload your session and you're good to go.

---

To remove other indicators, check which are installed with :

```
dpkg -l | grep indicator
```

And you can `sudo apt-get remove packagename` the one you don't want. Reinstalling them is easy, just do `sudo apt-get install packagename`. Don't forget to reboot or reload after installing/uninstalling an indicator.

There was no bad news :)

Comment: Actually `indicator-printers` refers to another one that shows up when there's a print job, but the one I want to remove is for the application hplip.  So the bad news... since it is an external application, they are all called `libappindicator` and `libindicator` with different numbers.  Would you know of a way to identify which one it is, or should I remove each one until I hit the one?