# how to get rid of icons on unity's top right bar

Tags: 14.04

I was wondering how to remove applications from unity's top right bar in ubuntu 14.04.

i have tried looking in .local and have looked in settings but found nothing.

i have seen a few posts on this before but none have been for 14.04 and more importantly, none have worked.

Comment: which icon specifically? I'm sure each one has a different package to un-install or some may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the indicators. The basic way of removing indicators is via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove my-weather-indicator.
sudo apt-get remove battery-status-indicator.
sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator
sudo apt-get remove indicator-me indicator-messages.
```

etc for for respective indicators. This and some other methods are mentioned in an earlier post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74986/how-to-hide-items-in-unitys-top-panel) (Since you are not telling us which solutions you have tried, it is not easy to know if you have tried them out already.)

Moreover, some indicators (at least) may be removed via the GUI, such as the keyboard layout indicator, as described [here](http://th0th.me/log/how-to-remove-keyboard-layout-indicator-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to remove items from the Launcher, then all you have to do is Right Click the icon, then select "Unlock from launcher". If it doesn't give you that option, then that icon cannot be removed.